# YUI getting selected value from drop down list

Tags: yui

How can I get selected value from a drop down list using YUI.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the combobox demonstrated here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about something like the combobox found here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html

You can get the value from the element's value property.  e.g.

```
document.getElementById("text_box_id").value
```

To see this in action, go to the above link, select a value for the first input box, then past the below code into your browser's address bar:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementById("bInput").value);
```

Comment: Thank you John , I thought that there is another way for doing it using yui element selections but this can help.